# Play job again after I have completed it as leader?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have already completed the Fleeca Job as leader. Whenever I go to my apartment it tries to start 'Prison Break'. I want to do the Fleeca Job. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

To replay heists that you have already completed, you need to cancel your current heist. Then call Lester, select "Replay A Heist," and choose which one you want.

You can use this to request specific heists. You can call anyone who offers you jobs to request that they send you a job, but they'll send you a random one from the list of jobs you have completed for them. You also need to wait a bit in between requesting jobs from the same individual if you are looking for a specific mission, roughly a minute or two between requests.

Comment: Does this work for all jobs or just Heists?

Comment: You can use this to request specific heists. You can call anyone who offers you jobs to request that they send you a job, but they'll send you a random one from the list of jobs you have completed for them. You also need to wait a bit in between requesting jobs as they'll give you snarky comments if you request multiple jobs from the same character in a row.